# Is there a way in SAS to flag records that have values after a 'certain value' across columns?

Tags: sas, data-cleaning

[image]

```
data have;
    length col1-col10 $2.;
    input col1-col10;
    datalines;
PM MM JM MM PM MM MM PB . .
MM JM PM MB . . . . . .
MM MM PM JM PB MM . . . .
PM PM PM MM MB MM JM . . .
;
run;
```

Goal:
Hi all,

My goal here is that I want to flag all records which have values other than 'PB' or 'MB' after them in sequence across the columns.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Expected output:

```
                           Flag
PM MM JM MM PM MM MM PB . .  0
MM JM PM MB . . . . . .      0
MM MM PM JM PB MM . . . .    1
PM PM PM MM MB MM JM . . .   1
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output? It's difficult to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Stu, I have added my expected output. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one array and `whichc` to find the index of where MB or PB is in the columns and then you can find the first non missing column index and then make a flag off these two variables. This will work if all the missing is at the end (as coded in your example).

```
data want1;
set have;
array s(*)  col1-col10 ;
max=max(whichc('PB', of s[*]),whichc('MB', of s[*])) ;
max2=whichc(' ', of s[*])-1 ;
if max2 > max then fl = 1;
else fl =0;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

After scratching the memory banks I remembered that naming syntax can list variables in **reverse** order!

I read the manuals way...

```
data work.want;
  set work.have;
  flag = cats(of col10-col1) not in: ('PB', 'MB');
run;
```

Seems like an obvious way...

If all rows have at least one PB or MB you can loop from end of array to 1 and flag if first value is not PB or MB.

If a row can be without either PB or MB you would have to check for that as well.

Example:

Leave checking loop as soon as first value encountered is evaluated for flag condition.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array col col1-col10;
  do i = dim(col) to 1 by -1;
    if not missing(col(i)) then do;
      flag = col(i) not in ('PB', 'MB');
      leave;
    end;
  end;
```